# Object showing instead of String when received through a stream

Tags: java, swing, stream, nullpointerexception, client-server

Hopefully I don't need to flood this post with my code, but if needed, please ask.
Also, I only used `getPassword().toString()` for testing purposes, and I don't use it in any of my applications.

Client-Side:
Grab password from `JPasswordField passfield`, send it as a String through `ObjectOutputStream out`

Server-Side:
Receive String through `ObjectInputStream in`, print it to console

Easy enough, but the problem I'm having is that instead of the String showing, it prints an object ([C@6af3a631)
The way I'm sending and receiving objects is pretty simple:

Client:

```
out.writeObject(passfield.getPassword().toString())
```

Server:

```
Object data;

while((data = in.readObject) != null) {
    if(data instanceof String) {
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

If I send `"hey"` instead of `passfield.getPassword().toString())`, the String prints out just fine.
I have been getting pretty familiar with ObjectOutputStream, and I've never encountered this problem, so I'm guessing it might have to do with the `JPasswordField`

This is a small step towards helping me understand bigger problem (packet containing password is sent just fine, packet is received just fine, but the password var comes in as null).

Comment: `passfield.getPassword().toString()`  **Never call that.**  `String` instances might hang around in the JVM to be stolen, so don't ever convert a password to a `String`.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, this is only for testing purposes. I thought the char[] was possibly causing some interference at the time, so I sent it as a String to check

Comment: @AndrewThompson and instead do...? It would be nice of you to, with saying "*don't do that*", also say what to do instead.

Comment: The code you've presented wouldn't even compile. Please show *actual code* otherwise we can't tell whether the problem is in the copying or the original code. A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would be ideal...

Comment: @Jon There are a bunch of questions with code that won't compile (and with no code at all). I just need help understanding the concept of why "hey" sends just find, but "getPassword()" is causing me issues. I was hoping that I wouldn't have to write up any example code, but I'll get right on that

Comment: @VinceEmigh: Yes, there are lots of bad questions on Stack Overflow. That's not a good reason to add more :) If you're going to post code, make sure it's useful to do so. If you don't think it's worth your time posting compilable code, don't post any code at all. (The exception is if you're trying to work out why something doesn't compile, of course.) See http://tinyurl.com/so-list and http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for my suggestions for writing good questions.

Comment: You're right. Why ask questions when you can just post your code and have people do the work for you, yeah? I'll try to follow the trend next time.. Either way, I wrote a test app, and it works just fine, so apparently it has to do with something non-relative to this situation. As the title states, I was wondering why the Object was showing, rather than the actual String, and you've answered my question, so for that, thank you. No need to down me for actually asking questions, seeing how this obviously isn't the worst question out there. Don't let that useless rep get the best of you, sir :)

Comment: @EelLee  That information comes to the OP that a) Doesn't already know (it seems Vince already does), and.. b) Has the common sense to ask.  --  SO is not a help-desk.  If instead you want to know what to do, I suggest you [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) on that (after doing some research - this has been covered many times).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `toString()` on a `char[]`. That doesn't do what you think it does - it will return something like "[C@6af3a631" because arrays don't override `toString()`. You end up with the default implementation of `toString()` from `Object`:

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object.

You *can* use:

```
// Eek - security problem!
out.writeObject(new String(passfield.getPassword());
```

... but that would leave a string hanging around in memory, which can't then be cleared. It's also transmitting the password in plaintext, which is awful unless this stream is secured in some other way.

I suspect you can just use:

```
out.writeObject(passfield.getPassword());
```

which will transmit the `char[]` as an object, and you'll get the same `char[]` out at the other end. It doesn't solve the "transmitting a password" problem though - and you'll still need to clear the `char[]` afterwards to avoid the password being accessible in memory.